# SELECT statement not working in mariadb 10.0 but works in mariadb 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

For some reasons, the following select statement does not execute in mariadb 10 but executes well in mariadb 5.5. In 5.5 it picks values from a database in those two time ranges. Fails to pick any on 10. with the same database. What could the problem be? Anyone?
Thank you.

```
$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;

$t1 = $_SESSION['post-data']['t1'];
$t2 = $_SESSION['post-data']['t2'];
$time1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t1);
$time2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t2);

$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT msisdn FROM customer WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time_paid,'%Y-%c-%e') 
     BETWEEN ADDDATE('$time1',INTERVAL 0 HOUR) 
        AND ADDDATE('$time2',INTERVAL '23:59' HOUR_MINUTE)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "Number of Recipients: ";  echo "$result->num_rows <br> <br>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $mobilenumber[] = $row['msisdn'];

    }
} else {
    echo "No Contacts to Display";
}

$mob_numbers = implode(", " , $mobilenumber);
echo "$mob_numbers";
$_SESSION['numbers'] = $mob_numbers;
```

Comment: you are using which mysql version?

Comment: In `Server version: 5.5.49-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)` works fine but in `Server version: 10.0.26-MariaDB-1~precise mariadb.org binary distribution` fails.

Comment: Are there errors? Wrong result? Are you having the same data in both databases?

Comment: @Philipp same data. No error but the echo No Contacts to Display

Comment: Just `echo $sql;` to check if there is something different...

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother using `DATE_FORMAT` assuming time_paid is `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.  That will let you use an index.  Then add this composite `INDEX(time_paid, msisdn)`; it will be helpful and "covering".

Then change the `BETWEEN` to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT msisdn
    FROM customer
    WHERE time_paid >= $time1
      AND time_paid  < $time2 + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```